# the variable of the function in python is not getting created in variable explorer in spyder e.g y_pred1 etc

Tags: python, machine-learning, spyder

"the variables are not getting created in spyder variable explorer after running the function. "

```
def apply_logistic_regression(X_train_data,y_train_data,X_test_data,y_test_data):
#import libraries
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve,precision_recall_curve
#fit and predict
classifier1=LogisticRegression()
classifier1.fit(X_train_data,y_train_data)
y_pred1=classifier1.predict(X_test_data)
#return y_pred1
#calculating metrics
logistic_regression_metrics={}

false_positive_rate, true_positive_rate,thresholds=roc_curve(y_test_data,y_pred1)
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_test_data,y_pred1)
logistic_regression_metrics={'precision':precision[1]}
return logistic_regression_metrics
```

Comment: Please format your code and add an error message.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is the fact that you have something called "function scope".

The variables will only be visible within the function. If you want to use the variable explorer from Spyder, you have to make them visible globally.

One naive way would be to simply add the function code in your `main()` function, or alternatively add the `global <variable_name>` to make it visible.